# I get the quotes garbled when getting rss feed titles with cURL and php

Tags: php, curl

I use cURL to get an rss feed from my own wordpress blog to display it as a "feed" sidebar and when I get the headers, all quotes appear as this : â€™

The cURL code I use to get that is:

```
$ch = curl_init($feed_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
```

The strange thing is that in my local server, it brings the quotes ok, but on the remote, it returns this seq.

The code I use to print out the "Feed" follows:

```
$x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
    foreach ($x->channel->item as $entry) {
        echo "<li class='newsLI'><a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->title . "</a></li>";
    }
```

and what I get, can be clearly seen in the bottom left side of the screen here: 
http://www.inlinkz.com

Any ideas on where to start looking for an answer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't have a `DOCTYPE` defined
2. You aren't setting the page's `content-type`

Adding the following lines to your code solved your problem (at least on my machine ;)):

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

(of course, this should be set to whatever definition you're actually using)

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" 
        content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That did the trick!! I didn't us the Doctype as it changed my layout. I will have to fix it at the test server first and then upload it. The content type was right on the money. Thanks again!!!

Comment: If the question is answered, please mark the response as being correct.

Answer (score 0):

Three lines of code below work for me, and I think they should work globally.

1. `$settings['rss_strip']="1200";`
2. `$row['summary'] = $admin->partial($row['summary'],$settings['rss_strip'],0);`
3. `$html .= '<description>'. $this->superhtmlentities( strip_tags($row['summary'] )    ).'</description>\n';`

The very simple trick lies in the variable declaration in the first statement of code, which when called in the second and third (function `strip_tags`) statements of code shows the rss-feed correctly (in my case) with unicode characters of any length.
**Note:** The value you assign to `$settings['rss_strip']` is important. The bigger the value, the more probability of SUCCESS.